# PHP Fatal error: 'SoapClient' not found

Tags: php, opencart, soap-client

I am running opencart store and I have a problem with an extension (about products delivery) that uses SOAP.

When I am trying to edit shipment options for that extension on my opencart admin account i get a 
`"Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in "` + path to the extension install directory.

I have a phpinfo(); page that shows information about the PHP instalation and there is no SOAP section. I have access to the php.ini file that controls PHP code that runs on my hosting account so I checked for an `;extension=php_soap.dll`. I found it, removed the comment (;) and nothing happens. The phpinfo(); page stays the same.

My web hosting provider is IPage.

My current version of PHP is 5.5.

I am sure that the delivery extension is working properly (I have another opencart instalation on my personal computer so I can test how everything works).

I red every thread about this topic and I tried every proposed solution without any result.
Can you please help me fix this fatal error?

EDIT_1:

It seems that IPage have some problems or I am not doing something right.

I am changing the php.ini file from the IPage Control Panel. According to [this](http://www.websitesetuptraining.com/ipage-features/ipage-php-info-configurationsettingsversion/) article, this is the correct way to change the PHP configuration:

> You can change the configurations of PHP on your website by changing
>   the php.ini located in your control panel. Just follow these
>   instructions to modify your PHP configurations:

But when I change mysqli settings like:

```
; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
```

FROM:

```
mssql.max_persistent = -1
```

TO

```
mssql.max_persistent = 20
```

the change does not appear in my phpinfo(); page. So I am thinking is there any other way to change the php.ini file? 
In the info page I can see:

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path:
>     /usr/local/lib/php-5.5.22-amd64/lib

But in my root folder I cant see anything like that.

Comment: Did you restart the web server after changing the php.ini? Also, check that you edited the _correct_ php.ini (phpinfo tells you which one is eventually used.)

Comment: I dont know how to restart the server, so probably no. I dont see any restart options. 

I dont think I am changing the correct php.ini. I will try to edit my question with more information about this. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is problem on the IPage site, they don't have probably installed php-soap extension.

When you remove the comment (;) `;extension=php_soap.dll` you should have possibility to restart `apache`, but you don't have this permission? I don't have account on IPage, but if you don't have access to install new extension you can only send them message, and maybe they can install php-soap for you:

```
yum install php-soap
apt-get install php-soap
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, 

I dont have any option to restart the server - just a "Save" button after I edit the php.ini. I will send them a message.